# What RedisCacheOptions.InstanceName is needed for?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm adding Redis in my ASP.NET Core project and using [`Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.StackExchangeRedis) to set it up (i.e. `services.AddStackExchangeRedisCache(opts => ... )`). `opt` is of type  [`RedisCacheOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.redis.rediscacheoptions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2), one of properties is the one in question - [`RedisCacheOptions.InstanceName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.redis.rediscacheoptions.instancename?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.2). I was not able to find a lot of info about it (except that it is Redis instance name) and I'm wondering when it should be set up and what it is used for (right now everything is working on my machine without setting it up)?

Answer (score 19):

It seems the instance name can be used if you want to use your cache with multiple apps/services.

If you look into the source code for [RedisCache.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a450cb69b5e4549f5515cdb057a68771f56cefd7/src/Caching/StackExchangeRedis/src/RedisCache.cs#L49-L60), you see in the constructor a comment describing the usage:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I would say that it would be nice to expand it a little bit though:  after browsing through the code (and playing with code and Redis) I saw that `InstanceName` is just used as prefix for Redis key.

Comment: How i understand 'instancename' is just prefix for cached data to understand which instance of our app is cached that data?